# Android, what type of pop-up windows are shown in true caller(when call is received) or assitive touch app(Android)

Tags: android

Please find the image link, i'm able to show a floating view similar to the one in image from my service, but not able to dismiss when Home or Back button is pressed. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKsQE.png

How does trueCaller or other apps which show such floating views, dismiss when device Home or Back Button is pressed

Comment: could you make this any clearer? im at a complete loss here.

Comment: Sorry that i couldn't make it clear, check the image for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation of the modal view (the correct term for "floating view"), there should be a listener for button presses. Im guessing you used a dialog?

Try something like this:

```
//create dialog as usual, lets call it myDialog
myDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCancel(Dialog dialog){
        dialog.dismiss(); //or whatever else should happen on back button touch
    }

});
```

There are a few more options, but i think this is best.
Let me know if it works for you.

EDIT: Heres a link to the docs to android's DialogInterface. You can find all the stuff you can do to (or with) dialogs there:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html